# I want to populate radio button input with json data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have data that I want to use to populate radio buttons, but some of the data length is longer then others and don't want empty buttons if the length is only one. I could be over thinking but I'm suck.

I've tried mapping through the props.size data so I could just populate it that way but I get an error that says map is not a function.

Here is my Button file:

```
import React from "react";

const EyewearPurchaseBtn = (props) => (
    <div>
        <form className="eyewear-purchase-form">
            <h3>Select Size</h3>
                <div>
                    <input className="radio-btn" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
                    <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">{props.sizes}</label><br/>

                    <input className="radio-btn" type="radio" />
                    <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">Two</label><br/>

                    <input className="radio-btn" type="radio" />
                    <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">Three</label><br/>

                    <input className="radio-btn" type="radio" />
                    <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">Four</label>


                <button onClick={props.handlePurchaseEvent} className="buy-now">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
);

export default EyewearPurchaseBtn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried mapping through the props.size data so I could just populate it that way but I get an error that says map is not a function.

This error means you tried to call a function (in this case, `map`) on an object that doesn't have that function available. This is usually for one of two reasons:

1. You misspelled the name or have the capitalization wrong
2. The object you're calling the function on isn't what you expect (i.e., a type error)

In this case, it's almost certainly the latter: whatever data you are calling `map` on isn't an array. Perhaps it's `null` or `undefined`, or it's a different type of object. You haven't shared that code, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: I figures it out actually! My initial state was `undefined` and when I was trying to extract out by index I was getting an error. I changed `undefined` to an empty array.  Thanks for helping I only checked cause you mentioned `undefined`!